# Autologin with LightDM on Xenial (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, auto-login

How to setup autologin on Xenial with lighdm from a terminal (i.e. with an editor)?

Here is what I currently have done.

First I created the conf.d-dir which did not exist on my installation:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
```

then I added to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/12-autologin`

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=<username>
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

(using `[Seat:*]` I took from [the Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Configuration)).

However, it does not work.

Comment: I assume you have entered your own user for the autologin-user=user parameter? If so, see in /var/log/lightdm/ if you can find any clues.

Comment: It's seems to be now `/etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` where lightdm is looking. Not /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/. But still `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` for the normal .conf-file. Is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe you can simply go to the *User accounts* menu of the system configuration and set the autologin option for your account.

Comment: I don't have gnome-setting installed. Running Kubuntu and using lightdm. Don't ask why, but it is was I need.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/12-autologin` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/12-autologin.conf` allow autologin.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work based on documentation. I made this configuration and restarted lightdm:

```
sudoedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/12-autologin.conf
```

Add this text:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=<username>
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Run

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: It is working in a system upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you didn't use *.conf as the extension on your file?

As per your reference:

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```